# best way to subtract mean monthly values for each grid in Python xarray

Tags: python, python-xarray

A toy dataset from [here](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/examples/weather-data.html#Toy-weather-data):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

import xarray as xr

np.random.seed(123)

xr.set_options(display_style="html")

times = pd.date_range("2000-01-01", "2001-12-31", name="time")
annual_cycle = np.sin(2 * np.pi * (times.dayofyear.values / 365.25 - 0.28))

base = 10 + 15 * annual_cycle.reshape(-1, 1)
tmin_values = base + 3 * np.random.randn(annual_cycle.size, 3)
tmax_values = base + 10 + 3 * np.random.randn(annual_cycle.size, 3)

ds = xr.Dataset(
    {
        "tmin": (("time", "location"), tmin_values),
        "tmax": (("time", "location"), tmax_values),
    },
    {"time": times, "location": ["IA", "IN", "IL"]},
)
```

I know that [here](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/examples/weather-data.html#Calculate-monthly-anomalies) I can find how to subtract mean monthly values from a variable in `xarray.DataSet()` as below:

```
climatology = ds.groupby("time.month").mean("time")
anomalies = ds.groupby("time.month") - climatology
anomalies.mean("location").to_dataframe()[["tmin", "tmax"]].plot()
```

Then, can I do the subtraction for each location?

I tried to do it for location-month groups, but the `xarray.DataSet.groupby()` doesn't allow to pass multiple groups. Then, I tried to make the location-month using `xarray.DataSet.stack()`, but it only allows to pass dimension; I could extract month values using `time.month` but they were restored as a new variable, not a dimension. I can use `for` or `xarray.DataSet.apply()` for all locations, but it is too slow (I have about 65000 locations).

Expected results or processes are something like:

```
for each location:
    climatology = ds.groupby("time.month").mean("time")
    anomalies = ds.groupby("time.month") - climatology
```

A solution within only `xarray` would be the best, but if it is possible and quite fast using `pd.DataFrame()` or others, then those solutions are also welcome.

## Edit

Here is my current solution using `pd.DataFrame()'

```
# convert to pd.dataframe
df = ds.to_dataframe()

# get mean monthly values
months = df.index.get_level_values('time').month
df_meanMonths = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(level='location'), months]).mean()

# rename and reindex
df_meanMonths.rename(columns={'tmin': 'tminMM', 'tmax': 'tmaxMM'}, inplace=True)
df_meanMonths.index.set_names('month', level='time', inplace=True)

# merge
df['month'] = df.index.get_level_values('time').month
vars_join = ['tminMM', 'tmaxMM']
join_right = df_meanMonths[vars_join]

# results
df.reset_index().set_index(['location', 'month']).merge(join_right, how='left', left_index=True, right_on=['location', 'month'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you might be looking for is this:

```
anomalies = xr.apply_ufunc(
    lambda x, mean: x - mean, 
    ds.tmax.groupby('time.month'),
    ds.tmax.groupby('time.month').mean()
).drop('month')
```

for just the tmax variable (a DataArray) or

```
anomalies = xr.apply_ufunc(
    lambda x, means: x - means, 
    ds.groupby('time.month'),
    ds.groupby('time.month').mean()
).drop('month')
```

for all variables in the Dataset

Comment: Thank you! The process your code implements looks as I intended, but I'm not sure about the result. For example, I compared the mean of tmin that was calculated within `apply_ufunc()` by the difference of tmin and anomalies (i.e., ds.tmin.values - anomalies) and one calculated from the array of tmin (i.e., np.mean(ds.tmin.values)), and found that they are not exactly the same (-5.16275 vs. -5.34013 for January 2000, for example). Would it possible for you to elaborate on this?

Comment: Hey you weren't very clear in your comment. From what I understood you are trying to compare the subtraction with the monthly mean: ds.tmin.values - anomalies sould be equal to the actual climatology. I did `(ds.tmin - anomalies.tmin).sel(time='2000-01-01', location='IA')` and `ds.isel(time=(ds.time.dt.month==1)).mean('time').sel(location='IA')` and both gave the same result (-5.16275)

Comment: Hi, you are right. I made a mistake during my validation. Thanks!